# Linux Printing - How To

Tags: c++, linux, terminal

I find it hard to explain but I will try my best. 
 Some times in Linux-  in the Terminal- things get printed but you can still write over them. eg when using wget you get a progress bar like this:

```
[===================>           ]
```

Now if you type something while it is doing this it will 'overwrite' it. My question is how to recreate this in c++.

Will you use something like

```
cout <<
```

or something else?

I hope you understand what I am getting at...

btw I am using the most recent version of Arch with xfce4

Comment: You need to consult your terminal's documentation and look for control characters that move the cursor around.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Printing a carriage return character `\r` is typically interpreted in Linux as returning you to the beginning of the line. Try this, for example:

```
std::cout << "Hello\rJ";
```

The output will be:

```
Jello
```

This does depend on your terminal, however, so you should look up the meaning of particular control characters for your terminal.

For a more cross-platform solution and the ability to do more complex text-based user interfaces, take a look at [ncurses](http://www.gnu.org/software/ncurses/ncurses.html).

Answer (score 2):

You can print the special character `\b` to go back one space.  Then you can print a space to blank it out, or another character to overwrite what was there.  You can also use `\r` to return to the beginning of the current output line and write again from there.

Comment: This may or may not work; there's no guarantee.  (On the earliest systems I worked on, the "terminal" was a real tty.  And once a character was printed, it was printed.)

Comment: I don't think we are in very much danger of the OP using an actual teletype machine.  :)

Comment: Agreed.  But if the output is redirected to `lpr`, he might not get what he wanted either.

Comment: And just to be clear: I'm just nitpicking.  Your suggests will work on a modern Linux machine.  or, I think, on any Unix system where the output is going to an `xterm`, or something similar. And probably even in a Windows console window, although I've never tried anything similar there.

Answer (score 1):

Controlling the terminal involved sending various escape sequences to it, in order to move the cursor around and such.

http://www.ibiblio.org/pub/historic-linux/ftp-archives/tsx-11.mit.edu/Oct-07-1996/info/vt102.codes

You could also use ncurses to do this.